# Attempting to launch an Activity from a standalone AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog in its own Java class. One of the options are meant to launch an Activity, but that seems impossible at this point, since I always end up with an `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

This is the AlertDialog's code, YallDoneDialog.java:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class YallDoneDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private Context mContext;

    public YallDoneDialog() {

    }


    public static YallDoneDialog newInstance(String title) {
        YallDoneDialog frag = new YallDoneDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.done)
                .setTitle(R.string.done_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.y, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MenuActivity m = new MenuActivity();
                        String resName = m.getResName();

                        LaunchBill l = new LaunchBill(mContext, getActivity());
                        l.LaunchTheDuckingBill(resName);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.n, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


}
```

You will see that a method called LaunchTheDuckingBill from LaunchBill.java is called as the action for the positive button. Here is that code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class LaunchBill {

    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public LaunchBill(Context mContext, Activity mActivity){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    public void LaunchTheDuckingBill(String resName){
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BillActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("resName",resName);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

This is the entire stack trace from the crash:

```
05-13 20:45:10.836 21191-21191/com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill, PID: 21191
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4916)
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.LaunchBill.LaunchTheDuckingBill(LaunchBill.java:18)
        at com.whatamidoingwithmylife.splitbill.YallDoneDialog$2.onClick(YallDoneDialog.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Can you please show me where I'm going wrong? I've tried a multitude of solutions that give the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `mContext` is null in `YallDoneDialog` . You never assigned it a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Remove `private Context mContext;` from your `YallDoneDialog`.

Step #2: Replace `LaunchBill l = new LaunchBill(mContext, getActivity());` with `LaunchBill l = new LaunchBill(getActivity(), getActivity());`

Comment: You are the greatest. Thank you.